# Convert for-comprehension to LazyList

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I have

- a list of files (`filepaths`)
- a method that reads-in and processes a file (`loadData`)
- a method that calculate statistics over that file

I want to read the files only when we also need to calculate the statistics. The line below will loop over the filepaths, and returns its name and file contents.

```scala
for((name, path) <- filepaths) yield (name, loadData(path))
```

Is it possible to do such a for-comprehension for a `LazyList`, so that the `loadData`-part is evaluated lazily?

Answer (score 4):

`for comprehension` is just syntactic sugar for combinations of `flatMap` and `map` functions. You can do that you need just using map function:

```
def loadData(path: String): String = {
  println(s"launch loadData on $path")
  s"${path}_suffix"
}

val filePaths = Seq("p1" -> "path1", "p2" -> "path2")
val lazyList = filePaths.to(LazyList).map{
  case (name, path) => name -> loadData(path)
}
println(lazyList)
println(lazyList.force)

// output will be:
//LazyList(<not computed>)
//launch loadData on path1
//launch loadData on path2
//LazyList((p1,path1_suffix), (p2,path2_suffix))
```

Here we see `loadData` evaluates only when next element is needed.

Comment: It would be more efficient to do this: `filePaths.to(LazyList)`

Answer (score 1):

It's most definitely possible.

```
for ((name, path) <- filepaths) yield (name, loadData(path))
```

Is just syntactic sugar for

```
filepaths.map { x =>
  val (name, path) = x
  (name, loadData(path)
}
```

(that may not be what the compiler actually desugars it to (I forget whether there would be multiple functions (one to extract the pairs and one to call `loadData`) or not))

Since there's a `map` on `LazyList`, if `filepaths` is a `LazyList` it will work.

That said, it's not maximally lazy: getting the `n`th entry requires evaluating the `(n - 1)`th entry.

Of course, whenever you have a `Seq[(A, B)]` (or `Iterable[(A, B)]`/ `Traversable[(A, B)]`), it's worth considering if what you really want is a `Function1[A, B]` or a `Map[A, B]` (which can just be thought of as an easy way to construct a subset of `Function[A, B]`).

```
// assuming that filepaths is an `Iterable[(A, B)]`
filepaths.toMap.mapValues(loadData(_))
```

(Note that the `(_)` might be able to be omitted).

This will be non-strict (it won't call `loadData` until you lookup a given `name`), but it won't be maximally lazy (there's no memoization: every lookup will result in a `loadData` call).  If you want maximal laziness, you'd have to implement your own memoization.